# The Use of "Navigate(-1)" Fails to Return to Previous Location in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, reach-router

I am trying to create a simple "Back" button in Gatsby that returns the the previous page and retains the scroll position. This already happens when using the browser back button, but I'm struggling to produce a custom one. I've read in the Reach Router docs that you can add -1 as an argument to the navigate function to return to previous locations, but It instead throws the number value into the url and gives me a 404. Can someone give me an idea of what I've done wrong? Or if anyone else has managed to make a functional back button for Gatsby projects?

Here is my code-

```
import React from 'react';
import { graphql, navigate } from 'gatsby'
import Img from "gatsby-image"

import "./design.scss"

const designTemplate = (props) => {
  return (
      <section className="design">
        <div className="design__container">
        <h2 className="design__title">
          {props.data.design.title}
        </h2>
        <Img className="design__image" fluid={props.data.design.localImage.childImageSharp.fluid} />
        <p className="design__summary">
          {props.data.design.summary}
        </p>
        </div>
        <button onClick={navigate(-1)}>Go Back</button>
      </section>
  );
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find the solution? I have a similar problem where I get "This page is not created yet" as soon as I use the navigate() function.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're having here is just that you didn't define a callback function for your `onClick` handler.

Instead of this:

```
<button onClick={navigate(-1)}>Go Back</button>
```

…you want to do this:

```
<button onClick={() => { navigate(-1) }}>Go Back</button>
```

Comment: That is definitely part of my problem, but even with the change I'm getting a 404 on click sadly.

Comment: @TashaZuniga You might just want to use `window.history.go(-1)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your onClick must have a callback(arrow function) like this

```js
onClick={()=>{navigate(-1)}}
```

not

```js
navigate(-1)
```