# How can I invoke a callback within a React function component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

This is the code I have working right now from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62092877/8652920) answer, whose comments suggested using `window.history`. It works, but I'd prefer to go back correctly, using React router v6.

```js
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
import Cookies from "universal-cookie"; 

function Foo() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const cookies = new Cookies();

  if (cookies.get('foo') === 'bar') {
    window.history.go(-1);
    // () => navigate(-1); // this does not work
  }
  return (
    <div />
  )
}
```

You can see commented out what I wanted to do, but that's not legal I think. And if I just use `navigate(-1)` it doesn't work, like the original question I linked.

So is there a way to use `navigate` inside `Foo`?

Comment: @Quentin i updated the title, ty

Comment: This seems valid. Did `window.history.go(-1)` not work for you - what was the issue/error ? Or you can just say `navigate(-1)`. There is no callback function needed because this is not an `onclick`

Comment: `window.history.go` does the job but since I'm using `react-router` already, I think its more correct to use the library instead of the builtin `window` module? Also, `window.navigate` produces a ton of "React does not recognize the `textHidden` prop on a DOM element" errors in the console

Comment: Understood. Let's not use the `window.navigate` then. Let's use the `navigate` variable you got from the hook. Is there any issue when you replace `window.history.go(-1)` with `navigate(-1)`

Comment: @BaoHuynhLam yeah it appears that `navigate` has to be invoked from a callback, so @quentin 's answer looks like it might work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> () => navigate(-1); // this does not work
> ```

This **defines a function** which will call `navigate(-1)` when it is called.

You never call it.

---

The dirty approach is to simply not wrap it in a function, but the main render function of a component shouldn't have side effects.

Wrap it in an effect hook instead.

```
const Foo = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const cookies = new Cookies();

  const foo = cookies.get('foo');

  useEffect(() => {
      if (foo === 'bar') {
          navigate(-1);
      }
  }, [foo, navigate]);

  return (
    <div />
  );
};
```

Comment: is there a reason a lot of people like writing function components like `const Foo = ()` instead of `function Foo()`?

Comment: I could only speculate as to the reasons for the trend.

Comment: also, is there some performance benefit to reading the cookie outside `useEffect`?

Comment: No, there's a performance penality. The benefit is that if the value changes and the component re-renders it the effect will be triggered again (so if the value *changes to* `bar` then it will navigate).

Comment: just a small nit but my terminal is telling me `navigate` needs to be a dep of `useEffect` as well